# Produce new data frame from extracted grouped data

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I'm a Python novice. I'm trying to extract trip duration from a series of GPS fixes. There are multiple different tracks that I am trying to get information from and put the results into seperate data frame. The data looks like this (latitude and longitude columns excluded):

```
   track_id   DateTime         
0  track_1    2015-12-19 03:39:01 
1  track_1    2015-12-19 14:23:21 
2  track_1    2015-12-20 02:39:01 
3  track_2    2016-01-02 05:44:23 
4  track_2    2016-01-02 12:12:34 
5  track_2    2016-01-02 19:44:33 
6  track_3    2016-01-07 00:44:23 
7  track_3    2016-01-07 13:11:05
8  track_3    2016-01-08 00:44:24
```

The desired output would look something like this:

```
   track_id   trip_dur         
0  track_1    0 days 23:00:00 
1  track_2    0 days 14:00:10 
2  track_3    1 days 00:00:01
```

I've managed to produce this information as a series using `groupby` but can't quite work how to produce a data frame like my desired output. I'd like to do it in a more 'pythonic' way if possible.

```
#Calculate trip durations
trip_dur = df.groupby(['track_id'], sort=False)['DateTime'].max() - \
        df.groupby(['track_id'], sort=False)['DateTime'].min()
```

Any help appreciated, 
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there, basically you can call `reset_index` with `name` param to to restore the 'track_id' column and name the aggregated column:

```
In [44]:
(df.groupby('track_id')['DateTime'].max() - df.groupby('track_id')['DateTime'].min()).reset_index(name='trip_dur')

Out[44]:
  track_id        trip_dur
0  track_1 0 days 23:00:00
1  track_2 0 days 14:00:10
2  track_3 1 days 00:00:01
```